# Fraction Format in rdlc

Tags: c#, format, rdlc

I have a decimal number in one of my cells in tablix. I'd like to format it to fraction. like 3.50 to 3 1/2 ...

Do you have any idea how to do this like in excel? because there are no fraction format in its properties.

Answer (score 0):

It might seem like an overkill solution, but in the lack of other formatting options, you could add custom function to your report and convert decimal number to string formatted as a fraction. Here is sample of code (see function "MakeFraction") that could help: [convert decimal to fraction in VB](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/helpers/numbertofraction.htm)